# How to communicate between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have 3 classes 1. main 2. Master 3. Clients ( three instance). Master and client have a function increment where they keep increment a value and periodically clients (say every 2 secs) send that increment value to master and at random time each client should send message to other client which it choose randomly (say client1 send to client 2) . and when the maser receives the message it will do some calculation and broadcast the value to all cilents.

Main -------->

```
public class Sample_one{

public static final int PORT = 4444;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
Socket socket =server.accept();

Thread m1=  new Master(socket);
m1.start();


Client c1 = new Client();
Client c2 = new Client();
Client c3 = new Client();
c1.start();
c2.start();
c3.start();

}
}
```

Master ----->

public class Master extends Thread  {

```
private int inc= 0;
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = start + 10*1000; 
Socket socket;

Master(Socket socket){
    this.socket = socket;
}

@Override

public void run() {

    while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end){
        increment();

    //Method to read input from the client 

      }

}

private void increment(){   
    inc++;
    System.out.println("counter"+ inc);
}

}
```

Client -- >

```
    public class Client extends Thread  {

    private int inc= 0;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end = start + 10*1000; 

     public void run() {

    while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end){
        increment();

    //Method to send the value to the Master or other clients


      }

      }

     private void increment(){  
    inc++;
    System.out.println("counter"+ inc);
    }

     }
```

Am I going in current path?? How do I connect the master and client and client with other clients?? Whether Socket are the only way?? I am new Threads.

Comment: Communication between threads is done/discussed when the threads are in the same process. Sockets are for inter-machine communication (usually). Which classification are you in? You're mixing the two together.

Comment: I need to simulate this in a single machine only

Comment: Sounds overly complicated, which to me indicates bad design. I can see the clients communicating back and forth with master, but why do they have to talk to each other? Ideally you want threads to be as independent as possible, and maybe only share some data, not send messages back and forth between them.

Comment: "Smarter-sockets" alike **ZeroMQ** or **nanomsg** are very powerfull tools to help you setup/use your process-to-process messaging layer. Worth spend a week to read through the book, before starting to use a wrong multi-thread/multi-process/multi-host communication architecture. Python and many other programming languages' ports/binds/wrapper available for ZeroMQ, some for nanomsg too.

Comment: @ventsyv That is the requirement. The clients should be communicating with each other. Can I use Pipedstream for inter thread communication?

Comment: Depends. Pipes are blocking and I assume you want the thread to be doing something while it's waiting for messages?

Comment: @ventsyv The threads should keep increment the value till it receives the message

Comment: A little observation... instead of subclassing the `Thread` class it may be a better idea to implement the `Runnable` interface. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best thing would be to use pipes. Look at PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream classes for example. Once you open the pipes, to receive data you would do something like this:

```
//establish the pipe connection

while (pipe) //assuming someone will eventually close the connection
{
   while (pipe.available() > 0)
      buffer.addByte(pipe.read())

   //Do some other processing
}
```